# How to get dynamic data from instagram for a website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want stats from an instagram account so that I can take that data and display it on my website. The data that I want to be displayed on my site are followers, followings, and posts. How would I go about capturing the data then implementing it.

I haven't tried anything yet, I am sorry. Getting data from apps is a little new to me.

I want "followers" section to display the number of followers, "following" to display the number of people I follow, and "posts to display posts."

Answer (score 2):

You should take at the following link:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/